# Sublime Text 3 inconsistently gets stuck using build system

Tags: sublimetext3

I am configuring a Sublime Text 3 build system that simply runs a command to flash my embedded micro controller using JLinkExe. My simplified build system is show below.

I have tried to use "cmd" instead of "shell_cmd", both have the same results.

```
{
    "working_dir": "$file_path/..",
    "shell_cmd": "JLinkExe -if SWD -speed 4000 -CommanderScript board-release.jlink"
    //"cmd": ["JLinkExe", "-if", "SWD", "-speed", "4000", "-CommanderScript", "board-release.jlink"]
}
```

Expected behavior is to simply run the specified command and show the results in the "Build Results" window. This happens inconsistently but about every 5 times the build works and Sublime shows this:

[image: Build output]

```
Script processing completed.

[Finished in 1.5s]
```

The other approximately 4 tries it doesn't build and Sumblime's build status in the status bar with the Line/Column count hangs for about 5-10 seconds while showing the "Building" text. Then "Building" disappears and nothing shows up in the results window.

[image: Build output]

Comment: Does the Sublime console show any errors when the build doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it does actually. Here is what is says: 
```Running JLinkExe -if SWD -speed 4000 -CommanderScript board-release.jlink
Exception in thread Thread-192:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "./python3.3/threading.py", line 858, in run
  File "/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Default.sublime-package/exec.py", line 152, in read_fileno
    decoder_cls = codecs.getincrementaldecoder(self.listener.encoding)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'```

Comment: Hmm.. is this happening if you try to do back to back builds, or does it also happen if there's some delay in between attempts?

Comment: This happens pretty randomly. Sometimes it will do back to back builds. Sometimes it takes 5+ attempts to build.